# how to maximize result of a non linear algo using gradient search

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I have an array A that contains the last 10 years of data in the daily stock market prices (open and close).

I have a function F(A, x, y) that researches the Moving Average of closing prices of x days in A, and buys at y % below that price.

- x is the number of days (integer) used for calculating the MA,
- y is a float used to calculate the entry price.
  The output of that function is the profit returned on all the transactions it tests, calculated using fixed stop-loss and take-profit

I'm using boundaries as follow: x: (5,200) and y:(0.0005, 0.8)

I'm trying to find the values of x and y that maximizes the output (the profit) of F as fast as possible. Brute force is only an option if it's the best option.

I've been trying scipy minimize with different methods. They all give very different results. I suspect it's because not all of them are appropriate for the kind of problem i'm trying to solve.

I have very limited knowledge in maths. What's the best method given the nature of the function?

Comment: There is nothing reproducible here.

Comment: meaning i should process it as a black box function?

Comment: You say you want to use gradient search, but I can't see how you will get any kind of analytic gradient from your function, and it would be expensive to run many calculations to approximate the gradients numerically. It's likely to be quite non-linear, especially for shorter numbers of days used for the moving averages.